# Actual slope between two points from raster slope value

Tags: slope

We have our own raster map and I have raster pixel slope value on map which is calculated using formula as shown in the link below
[Pixel Slope Calculation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=How%20Slope%20works), which is used to show different color as per the pixel slope value. So for a given point I can have these slope value anywhere on the map.

Earlier for calculating straight line slope between two points, I used to read elevation difference and then calculate straight line distance between those two points and finally dividing these two values. But I think with these pixel slope value my calculation can be minimize.

Is it possible to calculate the same value using pixel slope values of these points? If yes then how?

Comment: What software are you using?  can you include some screenshots to indicate what you're trying to do.  Do you just want to extract the values from  your slope raster in a straight line between the two points?  Do you want the average slope between those two points?  I'm a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: edited. @Fezter. I want to calculate straight line slope using raster slope value, without doing elevation diff divided by straight line distance.

Comment: With slope only impossible. You also loosing sign

Comment: Agreed, @FelixIP.  I think the best you could do is work out the average slope between those two lines, which is not the same thing.

Comment: It all depends on the goal. Contour line will have a slope<>0. If it is cut and fill, makes sense. If it is a road sign does not